# Commitlint not working. git commit -m commitlint message showing unknown argument , husky existed with code 1 (error)

Tags: husky, git-husky, commitlint

git commit -m "feat: testing the commitlint library"
@commitlint/cli@16.2.3 - Lint your commit messages

[input] reads from stdin if --edit, --env, --from and --to are omitted

```
Options:
  -c, --color          toggle colored output           [boolean] [default: true]
  -g, --config         path to the config file                          [string]
      --print-config   print resolved config          [boolean] [default: false]
  -d, --cwd            directory to execute in
                                         [string] [default: (Working Directory)]
  -e, --edit           read last commit message from the specified file or      
                       fallbacks to ./.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG               [string]
  -E, --env            check message in the file at path given by environment   
                       variable value                                   [string]
  -x, --extends        array of shareable configurations to extend       [array]
  -H, --help-url       help url in error message                        [string]
  -f, --from           lower end of the commit range to lint; applies if        
                       edit=false                                       [string]
  -o, --format         output format of the results                     [string]
  -p, --parser-preset  configuration preset to use for
                       conventional-commits-parser                      [string]
  -q, --quiet          toggle console output          [boolean] [default: false]
  -t, --to             upper end of the commit range to lint; applies if
                       edit=false                                       [string]
  -V, --verbose        enable verbose output for reports without problems
                                                                       [boolean]
  -v, --version        display version information                     [boolean]
  -h, --help           Show help                                       [boolean]

Unknown argument: edit
husky - commit-msg hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

Comment: ... so you running a linter in a hook?  You will need to tell us about those.

Answer (score 11):

for **Windows OS**
I later solve the problem by going to my .husky folder and edit ***npx --no -- commitlint edit***  to ***npm commitlint --edit***

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx --no -- commitlint edit
```

to

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx commitlint --edit
```

Comment: Had the same Problem on MacOS but this solution worked.

Comment: I did it and it worked in Ubuntu too. Any idea on WHY this solution works?

Comment: I get the feeling the commitlint readme may be stale or has a typo. This solution worked for me too on MacOS. Originally I followed the README which failed.

Comment: I am unsure, as I did not test it, but from the docs `--no` was previously `--no-install`, which I assume is for use with `npm` and not `npx`. So that may be why... I'll assume that flag/option is not needed for `npx` executable.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx#compatibility-with-older-npx-versions

Comment: I added a line to the `"scripts"` entry in my package.json file reading `"prepare-commit-msg": "commitlint --edit"` and then set my husky `prepare-commit-msg` script to include `npm run prepare-commit-msg`. Now it works for me with GitHub Desktop on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

1. open the command line,
2. in the root directory of the project.

```
cd .husky
echo "Some commit message" | npx commitlint
```

if no message echo, it means successful.
else failure.

if successful, please try again commit with the message you just typed,
and it will pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
./node_modules/.bin/commitlint --edit "$1"
```